# Textview Data being used as conditional if statement

Tags: android, android-studio, if-statement, textview, conditional-statements

I would like to make a conditional if statement. So if textview says x then do y. Is this possible? I have been trying to use the following code

```
if(tvresult.getText() == ("Environment"){
    testView.setText("NotAssignYet");
```

The tvresult textview is showing the following text

```
   [
 {"Sensor Type": "Environment",
 "Sensor ID":"5a7de613e13508be088dc4a8",
 "Vendor Name":"Monnit",
 "Vendor ID": "5a7ddc2de13508be088dc4a7",
 "Project Location Name": "862 White Street, Dubuque, IA, 52001",
 "Project Location ID": "5a01c555ad63f900b5411eed",
 "Gateway Name": "Gateway Test - Planning Stage",
 "Gateway ID":"5b1836f3389a4eaa38ff887f",
 "Vendor Sensor Type": "Temperature Test - Planning Stage",
 "Vendor Sensor ID": "NotAssignedYet"}
 ]
```

Is it possible to do what I am asking?

Comment: It's possible but I think one should use Views for displaying data not for storing data. So I would prefer some POJO which contains the relevant data and then I would query that instead of the TextView.

Comment: What do you mean? @0X0nosugar

Comment: I think before the text got to be displayed by tvResult you must have had it somewhere else, e.g. in a String. I'd rather keep a String variable around for comparisons than using a View as a data repository. If you show me more of your code I can suggest what I'd like to change. Oh, and another very important thing in Java: you should use String.equals() for String comparisons. "==" only works with primitive data types (if your app was not working as intended maybe that was the issue)

Answer (score 1):

I see your aim, it's possible but not the way you're using it.

I think you have to use

> tvresult.getText().toString().contains("Environment")

rather than

> tvresult.getText() == "Environment"

since `tvresult.getText()` **contains more text** not only "Environment". So your code should be:

```
 if (tvresult.getText().toString().contains("Environment")){ 

   testView.setText("NotAssignYet");
}
```

**Keep in mind**: `tvresult.getText()` does not return **String** object, it returns **CharSequence** which does not have a `.contains()` method, so I used `.toString()` to convert it.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

To get the text inside the `TextView` you can do this:

```
 String strJson = tvresult.getText().toString();
```

And as it appears from your text, it is a `JSONArray`. So you have to parse it first to check for the `Sensor Type` (as I understand that's what you looking for).

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
.`
.
.
JSONArray jsonAr = new JSONArray(strJson);
JSONObject jsonOb = jsonAr.getJSONObject(0);
String sensorType=jsonOb.getString("Sensor Type"); 
if(sesorType.equals("Environment"){
    testView.setText("NotAssignYet");
}
```

this way you could also check for `Vendor ID` for example and do whatever you want.

Comment: my app crashes on opening when I use this. I think it is what I want. Why does it crash?

Comment: I figured out the last issue. How do I pass this back to the postman?